# Safe to use a common return for multiple DC power supplies?

Tags: power-supply, dc, parallel

I have four 12V DC power supplies powering four separate loads (12V LED light strips). Is it safe to use a common return path for all four loads?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNJt0l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes, in the level of abstraction you ask, it can't be a problem. However, current load questions arise that depend on your cabling, and noise questions that depend on your power supply. Since you specify neither, no specific answer is possible.

Comment: Please post more details about the DC power supplies: battery, unregulated transformer + rectifier, linear regulator, switching converter...

Comment: Yep. No problem. Go for it. Just make sure the common path has good current capability.

Comment: OK, assuming that they are *dumb* LED strips. If they are *programmable* LED strips, the ground reference for the data signal(s) could be an issue. You need to draw out the entire circuit if you are using programmable LED strips.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the total current and what the cable is rated for

Let's say each 12 V LED strip consumes 12 W, then each LED strip has 1 A flowing through it. For each LED strip, the ground wire needs to carry 1 A, from left to right in your schematic it will show 1 A, 2 A, 3 A and 4 A at the bottom.

Given my 12 W example you need a cable that is rated for 4 A, since you have 4 LED strips and 1 A per strip. According to [powerstream](https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm) you need 15 AWG or you can have several cables in parallel with higher AWG values.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe, but you may have common mode voltage problems on ground as the ground will be shared by all devices. This means you need to think about how much resistance the return path has and how much current will be running through it and if the resulting voltage difference will create a problem for your application.

Let's say you have a 0.1Ω wire and 1A (total), this means the voltage across the wire (R7) will be 0.1V. (V=I*R)

Now let's say each load is 1A, the voltage across R7 will be 0.4V

Keep in mind if the loads are not constant, the voltage will change across R7 and this could affect the brightness of the LED's or digital signalling.

In short, keep the resistance low by using large gauge wire or parallel the return paths as much as possible

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyj4ii.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>